# AWS Cloudformation error creating CachePolicy component

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to create the cache policy for cloudfront but the CachePolicy component fails me without specifying the cause.

I can't understand, do you have any idea why this happens?

**Cloudformation**

```
CDNCachePolicy:
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::CachePolicy
  Properties: 
    CachePolicyConfig: 
      DefaultTTL: 60
      MaxTTL: 60
      MinTTL: 180
      Name: "StandardCachePolicy"
      ParametersInCacheKeyAndForwardedToOrigin:
        CookiesConfig:
          CookieBehavior: all
        EnableAcceptEncodingBrotli: false
        EnableAcceptEncodingGzip: true
        HeadersConfig:
          HeaderBehavior: none
        QueryStringsConfig:
          QueryStringBehavior: all
```

**Error**

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::CloudFront::CachePolicy" (RequestToken: 958e950c-b658-3946-deb0-ca86d444a5e4, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry I just now tested your response. It works correctly! 
I didn't realize that I had inverted the values :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **TTLs are incorrect**. It should be:

```
                DefaultTTL: 60
                MaxTTL: 180
                MinTTL: 60
```